# pausing the textbox update till the http call is made WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

so I have a class `request` that has a method `call` that makes an http request

in my main class, when the user presses a button, an isntance of the class `req` is made and the method `call` makes the http request is invoked.

I want to have a certain way to know when the call is done so that I can update my textblock with the results

I tried to put that in the button click event handler method:

```
        req.call(textBox1.Text);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            //req is the class instance, outputMessage is the string holds 
            //the result of the http request
            //resultTextBlock is the one I wanna update with the result
            while (req.outputMessage == "none") ;
            resultTextBlock.Text = req.outputMessage;
        });
```

in the button click event handler, but then the app goes into infinite loop and never finishes, the http request takes fraction of a second to be made if that's matter

I want to be able to update the `resultTextBlock` whenever the result is grabbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a callback from the request once it is completed. This is supported i.e. by the `WebClient`:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"), null);
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        string outputMessage = e.Result;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
                resultTextBlock.Text = outputMessage;

        });
    };
}
```

**Edit:**

You could pass in a delegate to your `req` class that you pass the result string (also note the naming guidelines, should be all Uppercase), so change the method signature as follows:

```
public void Call(string url, Action<string> notifyCompletion)
{

 //once completed:
  notifyCompletion(result);
}
```

And change the calling code to:

```
Req myRequest = new Req();
myRequest.Call(textBox1.Text, s => 
{
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
       resultTextBlock.Text = outputMessage;
   });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the call is implemented in the separate class different from the main class, so resultTextBlock is not available to assign to

Comment: you could pass in a delegate as the second parameter to your `request` class - call that delegate in the completed event handler